# How do I drywall a corner with a lally column?

Tags: basement, framing

I'm finishing my basement and I've come across this lally column which is supporting a steel beam.  I want to frame an external corner for this interior wall at this "corner" but the distance from where the back of the drywall would be to the column (especially on the right side) is *really* small, like maybe 0.5"?   Since I can't fit a 1x1" there, how do I frame this corner?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my suggestion. It is only part of the post in the drawing, but it is the same all the way up, the scrap pieces of plywood are about 1 ft apart 3 or 4" wide, can be wider, can be solid, done that too. Makes for a really strong corner for corner bead. If you don't use 1/2" plywood and need to use 1/4" it will still be really strong. Using a full piece of plywood makes a straight corner really easy. It is what I do, I shown pieces so the method of construction is seen. I have also used 1X and had good results too, I use glue to help hold it....

[image: post corner]

Comment: That's a great drawing, worth a thousand words and an up vote.

Comment: Awesome drawing (what was it done in?).  One question - since this is a basement floor, are there any problems with having the plywood directly touching the floor?

Comment: I made the drawing using Trimble Sketchup, it used to be Google Sketchup. It is a free download and free to use. After I made the 3D drawing I set the best position, I exported it to a 2D drawing, which makes it a .PNG file, and I posted that. All kinds of tutorials on Youtube.

Comment: I forgot to mention about the plywood. On any surface in a basement I hold it up a bit, 1/2" is good for the plywood, but DO hold up the drywall 1". Cut off some of the tapered edge if need be. It really makes setting base difficult to set plumb, unless a shim is set at the bottom.

Comment: So basically just move the bottom part for the plywood and 2x2's up about 1/2"?

Comment: @Jack I couldn't figure out how to direct message you so here you go - Your answer was really helpful.  Any chance you could look at my other question http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/81383/how-to-build-a-wall-under-duct-work?  Also, are you still in the DC area or are in you WA state?

Comment: I was in the DC area up till a year ago, in WA state now... I will look at it. Yes, no need for it to touch the floor, you can layout a few pencil lines on the concrete floor that show the wall extension where it is to go and sight the corner from that.

Answer (score 1):

Use plywood as the corner material for both sides. The corner can be built on site and installed when complete. Strengthen the corner with brackets installed on the inside and construction adhesive. You'll need nailers on each end of the attachment walls.

You could also just extend the drywall without framing since the distance past the framing is minimal (glue the two pieces were they meet at the corner).

Answer (score 1):

Don't frame it, just wrap the ends of the walls with drywall to behind the column & paint the column to match or contrast. Or, you can make it decorative & give yourself room to boot. Screw a 2x8 & 2x10 into a corner with corner bead (guessing what it is to each end stud), then screw those flats to the wall end stud faces (only half the width of those studs so drywall can lay & screw)...Bumps-out just the corner (2" with drywall, if desired). It would look great & you can corner bead the bump-out to get all 3 corners sharp. [image: Here's a diagram]

Option 1 leaves the column accessible, but possibly difficult to mud & corner-bead. Option 2 could be removable with just screws at the very top & bottom...if desired. Pre-drill both the lumber corner & the wall studs so you don't split that 3/4" you'd screw Option 2 into.

Comment: Do you have an image of what you're talking about?  Seems like seeing the column would be really ugly

Comment: @2LeftThumbs I do now.