# Do wires running attached to joists need to be protected?

Tags: electrical, framing

So after asking [How to build a wall under duct work](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/81383/how-to-build-a-wall-under-duct-work) ,I was thinking of going the #2 route and running a top plate next to the existing wire.  Now, I've seen that when running wires through studs, you need a nailing plate if the wire is closer than 1-1/4" to the outside.  In this case, I would think that I'd be fine, but what if I were to instead go with a different solution and use some hat channel to fur down the ceiling.  Would I need to protect that wire and gas line somehow from stuff coming through the drywall ceiling (however unlikely that might be)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your hat channel is at least 1-1/2” deep it would meet code. (With the wires minimum 1-1/4” away from the bottom). If you want to lay the wires in the hat channel that would not be an approved method. I changed the depth to be 1-1/2" I forgot to add the wire thickness. If large wires your minimum space from the wire to the channel is 1-1/4" to meet code.